# Should we create specific tags for popular tools?

Tags: discussion, tags

Some tools and terms are used a lot. Should we create tags for these, even if they are rather specific?

Where should we draw the line for "a lot"?

For example, things like:

- [knife-tool](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+knife)
- [loop-cut](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20loop%20cut)
- [extrude](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=extrude+is%3Aquestion)

According to those search results, there are now a good 50 questions which could potentially use a [knife-tool](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knife-tool) tag.

We already have a few tags like this, such as [snapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snapping) and [3d-cursor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-cursor).

What are the possible downsides of adding these tags? What are the upsides?

How should we pick what tools deserve a tag? How many questions should there be asked about said tool before we consider making a tag?

Answer (score 9):

We definitively need these tags, the more exact a search result can be narrowed down, the better. Some would argue that all of those tags could be ignored and simply tagged Modeling.

[from the basic description of all tags](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/tags)

> A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, **similar** questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question.

Although a question about the knife tool could be tagged *modeling* and left at that, you could further tag it as knife-tool and make search results much more useful. however, that same question it would not necessarily also be about extruding, so I would argue that not only those three, but many more like them could be added. when you broadly tag something *modeling*, it can have *Many*, ***Many*** different questions that have nothing to do with each other. tags are meant to categorize questions that are similar so someone with a problem can easily find his/her/its solution.

This is the same situation with the **modifiers** tag and the **subdivision-surface** tag. someone could blindly throw on the modifiers tag and walk away, but it makes it much more difficult for an expert on a certain subject to assist that person.

Answer (score 2):

If there are downsides, I can't think of any. I think we'd have to go ahead with this and see if any pop up.

This idea has my vote, straight up.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the idea that the more specific you can make a question's tags the better. The only thing that might possibly be an issue would be that people might be tempted to add the non-specific ones first and use the available 5 up before getting to them, but I think this risk is negligible because of it's unlikelihood.

**I support this idea**, and I think we should go ahead with it.

Comment: I still think there should be a limit to how specific tags should be. IMO we don't want super-specific tags like `inverted-normals`, `non-manifold-geometry`, `undo-history`, etc. Though with the number of inverted normal questions we get, it'd almost be worth it if they weren't all duplicates :P

Comment: Exactly, it should be limited to tools and major techniques I think